# Are parameters replaced by the callers arguments before function execution even if they havent been evaluated, true in all cases?

Tags: function, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

Are parameters replaced with their respective arguments before function execution even if they havent been evaluated (I.E. irrespective of whether lazy or eager evaluation is used),true in all cases.

I want to understand whether we can generalise the statement:

Before a function is executed (irrespective of argument evaluation), the parameters are "assigned" to the arguments in the function call.

```
e.g. f(x,y)
    x +=1
    y +=1
    return x+y;
```

I call `f(1,2)`:

1. 1 and 2 is assigned to x and y
2. then the rest is executed

I call `f(2*3,5*6)`:

1. In eager evaluation 6 and 30 is assigned
2. In lazy evaluation `2*3` and `5*6` is assigned?

Please could you clarify, thank you!